# Variable id might not have been initilalized (JSP)

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Drops me this error when i am running the file... and i don't know what to do .... any help, an seems not to be an wrong in syntax...

```
      Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\ioann_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project
 ΒΔ\build\generated\classes
 C:\Users\ioann_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project
 ΒΔ\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\assets\jsp\create_002ddest_002dcode_0020_00282_0029_jsp.java:80:
 error: variable id might not have been initialized
               int insert_ch=myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Dest_has_Categories (Dest_idDest,Categories_idCategories) VALUES
 ('"+id+"','"+cat[i]+"')");
                                                                                                                                         ^ 1 error C:\Users\ioann_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project
 ΒΔ\nbproject\build-impl.xml:953: The following error occurred while
 executing this line:
 C:\Users\ioann_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Project
 ΒΔ\nbproject\build-impl.xml:296: Compile failed; see the compiler
 error output for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

The code

```
  <%


   String id8=request.getParameter("id8"); //Country field  
   String id9=request.getParameter("id9"); //City field
   String id10=request.getParameter("id10"); //URL field
   int id;

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
          String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
          Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
          Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  

           String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO dest(Country,City,URL) VALUES ('"+id8+"', '"+id9+"','"+id10+"')";
           myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
           ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT idDest FROM dest WHERE Country='"+id8+"' AND City='"+id9+"' AND URL='"+id10+"'" );
            while (rs.next()) {
                id=rs.getInt(1);
            }
           String cat[]=request.getParameterValues("dest1");

           for(int i=0;i<cat.length;i++)
           {
              int insert_ch=myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Dest_has_Categories (Dest_idDest,Categories_idCategories) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+cat[i]+"')");

           }
```

Comment: Did any of the answers provided solve your original problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `int id;` but you never set a value to it. You need to initialize (or set a value to it) before you can use it.

```
String id8=request.getParameter("id8"); //Country field  
String id9=request.getParameter("id9"); //City field
String id10=request.getParameter("id10"); //URL field
int id = -1;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_app?user=root&password=1234"; 
Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  

String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO dest(Country,City,URL) VALUES ('"+id8+"', '"+id9+"','"+id10+"')";
myStatement.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);
ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT idDest FROM dest WHERE Country='"+id8+"' AND City='"+id9+"' AND URL='"+id10+"'" );
while (rs.next()) {
    id=rs.getInt(1);
}
String cat[]=request.getParameterValues("dest1");

if(id > -1)
{
    int insert_ch;
    for(int i=0;i<cat.length;i++)
    {
      insert_ch=myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Dest_has_Categories (Dest_idDest,Categories_idCategories) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+cat[i]+"')");
    }
}
```

Try the above, I modified it so it should work fine for you. I also moved the declaration of `int insert_ch` outside of the for loop, otherwise it will be unusable elsewhere, unless you will be doing more stuff only within the loop using `insert_ch`.

Comment: 2nd option Error :   for(int i=0;i<cat.length && id != null;i++) incomparable types int and null   1st option : again same error

Comment: Try the last suggestion I added to my answer. You will need to ensure you do that anywhere you are trying to use `id`. The basic problem is that you aren't ensuring that either `id` is initialize, or your code is safeguarding against it being used in the case of uninitialized.

Comment: if(id!=null) says me again incomparable types

Comment: Sorry, had forgot we were talking about Java, for simplicity, just initialize your variable `id` to -1 then in the `for` loop check for it being > -1 and you should be golden. See the last example in my updated answer.

Comment: Just change your declaration if `id` from `int id;` to `int id = -1;`, then modify your for loop to be exactly what I have above... I guess I can modify the whole thing for you though. Give me a moment to do that.

Comment: again compile error.... can you give an alternative way to contact with to send you a screenshot ?

Comment: Updated with a few modifications.

Comment: i c-p it ... but... again compile error (not in code error ) but when i am trying to run it drops me compile error... bug? it isnt running now the other jsp pages saying compile error :P

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you getting an error on `id` still?

Comment: check if i run any jsp that i have in my project says me : rror: variable id might not have been initialized
              int insert_ch=myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Dest_has_Categories (Dest_idDest,Categories_idCategories) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+cat[i]+"')"); i think its a bug because i deleted and says me again the same...

Comment: Ensure your built solution is cleaned properly, get rid of any built binaries and rebuild everything and try running it again.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting "id" in a while loop, it may not get initialized if resultset is empty. This is the reason you are are seeing this compiler error. Initialize the id at declaration and you should be fine.
-Amit

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: @JohnV He suggested initializing it at declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id;
...
ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT idDest FROM dest WHERE Country='"+id8+"' AND City='"+id9+"' AND URL='"+id10+"'" );
while (rs.next()) {
   id=rs.getInt(1);
}
...
for(int i=0;i<cat.length;i++)
{
    int insert_ch=myStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Dest_has_Categories (Dest_idDest,Categories_idCategories) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+cat[i]+"')");
}
```

If the query does not return any rows the variable `id` will never get a value.

Comment: Also, if there are resultant rows found, the value of id is the idDest of the last row found. Is this what is really wanted? What if the idDest value of  the result set rows are not all the same? Can you guarantee that the query will always return the hits in the same order ? You are not sorting them, so they could come back in any arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Id=rs.getInt(1); //here
```

Id field is null or blank try to print or alert to see what value is coming in id .
That's the reason it's giving variable id might not be initialized

Comment: can you write me a suggestion?